# Assigning the variable inside the script and use it in same script

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, variable

```bash
echo -e '(b) \033[3;32m  for between hours\033[m';
echo -e ' please choose \033[32;5m (a or b)\033[m';
read option
#if [ "$option" == "a" ]
#then
        destination="/home/siva/test"
        echo -e 'date in format: \033[33;5m(mm-dd-yy) eg.10-30-22\033[m '       # date format of thread_dumps needed
        read -p "enter date : " D                               #enter the date of thread_dumps needed
        echo -e 'hour in format: \033[33;5m( HH )\033[m'
        read -p "enter Time (HH:MM) : " T   #enter specific hour of thread_dumps needed
        H= echo $T | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}'

        find=`find /home/siva/thread_dumps/thread_dump_"$D"_"$H"\:[0-9][0-9]\:0[1-2]`

        echo $find
        #cp $find $destination

       # zip -r /home/siva/zip/thread_dumps_"$D".zip $find
```

In the above script
I want to assign the variable `(H= echo $T | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}`). And I want to use the variable in the same script. But this doesn't work for me. I want `echo` output in a variable and use it in `find` command

Comment: Welcome to the site. I would recommend that you check your script with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), also available as stand-alone program in many Linux distributions, because it contains various syntax errors on the line where you want to assing `H`.

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be any use for the `find` command. You appear to want to use a globbing pattern (which includes the two variables `$D` and `$H`) to match a number of directories under `/home/siva/thread_dumps`, is this correct?  Also, if you want the _hour_ in "HH" format, why do you ask for the time in "HH:MM" format?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you want to assign `$H` _to_. Should it have the string `echo $T | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}'` or should it have the result of running the command `echo $T | awk '{print substr($1,1,2)}'`? Also note you cannot have spaces around the `=` in variable assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it looks as if you don't need `find` in your code.  You also don't need to do user interaction if you instead take the user's input from the command line arguments:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -u

# Usage:
#
# ./script MM-DD-YY HH
#

archive=$HOME/zip/thread_dumps_${1}.zip

if [ -e "$archive" ]; then
        printf '"%s" already exists\n' "$archive" >&2
        exit 1
fi

for dirpath in "$HOME/thread_dumps/thread_dump_${1}_${2}":??:??
do
        if [ -d "$dirpath" ]; then
                printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$dirpath" >&2
                zip -r "$archive" "$dirpath"
        fi
done
```

This script takes the date and the hour from the arguments given by the user on the script's command line.  It then uses basic filename globbing to match the directories that should be archived and does so one directory at a time. Modify the pattern to fit your needs.

A small change to this would be to make sure that the path `$HOME` is not stored in the archive so that the archive unzips into a `tread_dumps` archive.

You can do that by changing the loop into

```bash
for dirpath in "$HOME/thread_dumps/thread_dump_${1}_${2}":??:??
do
        if [ -d "$dirpath" ]; then
                printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$dirpath" >&2
                ( cd "$HOME" && zip -r "$archive" "${dirpath#$HOME/}" )
        fi
done
```